# How to control when to excute certain block of code in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

In my backbone project, when this page is rendered, I need to display an Edge HTML5 animation and after that, I need to trigger a Gumby modal click event.

My question is, is there a way to control the follow so that:

$('#modal').trigger(Gumby.click);  will be excuted after animation finished?

I tried to set local cookies or other approach but doesn't work.

Here is code structure:

```
    Myview = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize:function(){
        init:function(){
            var ajaxcall= $.ajax({

            });
            ajaxcall.done({

                _this.afterInit();

            });

            // Need to display this modal after the animation finish
            $('#modal').trigger(Gumby.click);
        },

        afterInit:function(){
            var anothercall= $.ajax({

            });

            anothercall.done({
                window.HTML5ANIMATION.playanimation(); //display Edge animation in an iframe

            });
        },
        .
        .
        .
        .
    },

    render:function(){

    }

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not set a boolean flag after the animation is over? Use `setInterval` to constantly check for the flag's value, and display the popup when it turns true. I'm sure you have control over the HTML5 animation code.

Answer (score 0):

Or, even better: trigger a DOM event at the end of the first task, and listen to this event to start the second task.

Comment: sometimes, need nested functions to achieve something.